# Insert the input body in a database with the SQL component from Camel

Tags: mysql, sql, apache-camel

I want to parse the content of xml files and create queries to insert/update some of the xml content in a database.
So far I am able to generate the SQL queries in a processor, populate the body with them, then I would like to run them with the SQL component.
**First please let me know if this is not the recommended way to do.**
(for instance I feel like the SQL component is meant to run only 1 query).

```
...
.process(new XmlToSqlProcessor())
.to("sql:${in.body}?dataSource=dataSource")
```

Doesn't work, ${in.body} is not replaced by its content (meaning the set of queries generated in the processor):

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '${in.body}' at line 1
```

Should I do all the work in the processor (I wanted to avoid all the database boilerplate though), or maybe use the JDBC component?
If yes can you confirm that the SQL component can only run 1 query and can not parse Simple Expression Language? (I also tried :#${body} that I saw there https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-7455 but as expected it's considered as a param, not a whole query)

Thanks!

**EDIT:** after more reading it seems like the SQL component and the JDBC component as well can execute only 1 query. So, having my own processor is apparently the only choice... let me know if I am wrong ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, sql component will execute only 1 query and will not evaluate ${in.body}. You miss two concepts in your route:

- Splitter (http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html)
- RecipientList
  (http://camel.apache.org/recipient-list.html)

Try something like:

```
...
.process(new XmlToSqlProcessor())
.split().body()
.recipientList(simple("sql:${in.body}?dataSource=dataSource"))
```

Comment: Spitter is a good idea, thanks! But I think your code is not correct, the body() should be inside .split() like: .split(body().tokenize(";"))